# Error when trying to select all items in listbox on button click event

Tags: c#

Error :

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'.

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListBox item in SelectTables_Listbox.Items)
        {
            item.SelectedItem = true;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(" All tables Selected ");
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Winforms?

Comment: `ListBoxItem` instead of `ListBox` is a wild guess, but the error message says it should be `string`. What type is `SelectTables`? Is it Winforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items in `SelectedTables.Items` are not `ListBox`es. In your case, each item is a `string`. The easiest method for selecting all elements would be something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SelectTables.Items.Count; i++)
{
    SelectTables.SetSelected(i, true);
}
```

Comment: @ShaliniPavan: Great! Please be sure to click the checkmark to accept this as the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to cast list box items into a ListBox ???

foreach (**ListBox** item in SelectTables.Items)

I am not sure what the type should be, but not ListBox